# nth-child selector while creating portfolio items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know this has been probably answered a bunch of times already, but I haven't been able to find the right answer. Here, nor Google for that matter. So I'm hoping someone might help me here.

I am trying to make portfolio section on a site, in which the items would be stacked in full width rows, and in each row 50% would be an image, and by that 50% description. I would like to make row interchangeably mix images and descriptions of items from left to right (on one row image is on the left and description on the right, and on the next row vice-versa, and so on).
I have tried using nth-child selector (odd/even), and nth-of-type, and it keeps selecting all divs.

I think I am being to dumb right now to figure it out by myself, and I'm guessing it's a simple solution, but I'm stuck.

Any help and/or suggestion about how to achieve it (even without nth-child) would be greatly appreciated!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mariopurisic/4qanLbov/

```css
#portfolio-items::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.item-image {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.item-description {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio-items">

  <div class="portfolio-items">

    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <h5 class="item-title">Item 1</h5>
      <p class="item-text lead">Item 1 Description</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <h5 class="item-title">Item 2</h5>
      <p class="item-text lead">Item 2 Description</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- .portfolio-items -->

</div>
<!-- #portfolio-items -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're making things a lot more difficult on yourself by not grouping your portfolio pieces with their descriptions.

Trying not to change your HTML too much, I just added `article` tags around each portfolio item and then selected the `article:nth-of-type(even)` and swapped the float properties.

```css
#portfolio-items:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.item-image {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.item-description {
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.portfolio-items article:nth-of-type(even) .item-image {float:right;}
.portfolio-items article:nth-of-type(even) .item-description {float:left;}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio-items">

  <div class="portfolio-items">

  <article>
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <h5 class="item-title">Item 1</h5>
      <p class="item-text lead">Item 1 Description</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="item-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <h5 class="item-title">Item 2</h5>
      <p class="item-text lead">Item 2 Description</p>
    </div>
  </article>

  </div>
  <!-- .portfolio-items -->

</div>
<!-- #portfolio-items -->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4qanLbov/1/

Comment: Thank you so much!

I actually was grouping them just as you did here, but since my selectors weren't working I thought it might have been because they were in separated tags. Which is silly obviously haha

Thanks again! ;)